# Cannot convert sparse tensors back to dense tensors after using torch.save and torch.load

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

If I simply do `to_dense()` right after `to_sparse`, it works

```py
x = torch.tensor([[[True, False],[True, True],[True, True]]])
x_sparse = x.to_sparse()
x_dense = x_sparse.to_dense()
```

But if I save my sparse tensors using `torch.save` and load it back using `torch.load`, it does not work any more

```py
torch.save(x_sparse, 'x.pt') 
torch.load('x.pt').to_dense()
```

> RuntimeError: "coalesce" not implemented for 'Bool'

What is wrong here?
I am using pytorch 1.10